# How can vite be configured to load relative images in stylesheets imported from node_modules?

Tags: uikit, less, vite

I have an application that uses UIkit, Less for local styling, and Vite for frontend tooling (bundling and whatnot).  I'm not sure that this is relevant, but this is a Vue 2/Webpack application that I'm upgrading to Vue 3/Vite.

Per [UIkit's Less documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/less), we import UIkit's `uikit.theme.less` file in our project's base less file.  UIkit's stylesheets have some relative paths to SVG files that get run through less's [`data-uri` function](https://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-data-uri) (examples below).  That worked fine with Webpack, but with Vite it's not quite working.  As I understand it, for small files, `data-uri` will UTF-8 encode the asset and essentially inline it--at least that's what we got in our Webpack bundles.  But with our Vite build, it seems these relative image paths aren't being resolved, `data-uri` hence falls back to a `url()`, and we get 404s for the images.

For example, in UIkit's code the *relative* path to a spinner image is defined [here](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/v3.12.2/src/less/components/form.less#L110); it's used in a `select.uk-select`.  And [here](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/v3.12.2/src/less/components/form.less#L436) that path is passed to a `.svg-fill` mixin ([here](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/v3.12.2/src/less/components/mixin.less#L11)).  When we bundle the code using Vite, or run a local dev server, the result is:

```
background-image: url(../../images/backgrounds/form-select.svg);
```

That, of course, doesn't load because the "images" directory is relative to the `form.less` file.  In Webpack, the output was as expected:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg width='24' height='16' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23001c30' d='M12 1 9 6h6zM12 13 9 8h6z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
```

For this type of question, I would normally include an HTML/CSS/JS snippet; however, I don't think SO supports Vite.  As such, I'm including a small Stackblitz that minimally demonstrates the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-esqmqc?file=main.js  Please see `main.js`, `style.less`, and note that there's a 404 error in the console complaining about the aforementioned `form-select.svg` file.

In case the question isn't clear, how can I get Vite to resolve images which are relative to a dependency in `node_modules`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A workaround is to configure [`resolve.alias`](https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias) to point `../../images` to `uikit/src/images` (which resolves to the `uikit` package under `node_modules/`). This tells Vite how to resolve the [problematic relative image paths](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/blob/v3.12.2/src/less/components/form.less#L110).

The `resolve.alias` config is passed to `@rollup/plugin-alias` as [`entries`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/alias#entries). Each entry can have a [custom resolver](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/alias#custom-resolvers) that can be used to only replace imports from UIKit. However, it requires that the import of `uikit.theme.less` be in its own file so that the custom resolver can correctly identify the importer in order to determine when to replace the import.

1. Put the import of `uikit.theme.less` in its own file, and import that from `main.js` (not from `style.less`):

```
// style.less
// @import './node_modules/uikit/src/less/uikit.theme.less'; ❌ move to own file
```

```
// my-uikit.less
@import './node_modules/uikit/src/less/uikit.theme.less';
```

```js
// main.js
import './style.less';
import './my-uikit.less';
```

2. Create `vite.config.js` with the following configuration:

```js
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { basename } from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: '../../images',
        replacement: '',
        customResolver(updatedId, importer, resolveOptions) {
          // don't replace if importer is not our my-uikit.less
          if (basename(importer) !== 'my-uikit.less') {
            return '../../images';
          }

          return fileURLToPath(
            new URL(
              './node_modules/uikit/src/images' + updatedId,
              import.meta.url
            )
          );
        },
      },
    ],
  },
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-uikit-pcdgbd?file=vite.config.js)

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer as it does provide a good workaround and it got our project moving.  That said, the issue is, IMO, a bug in Vite.  I fixed the bug and filed a PR (https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/7400), which was accepted and should be released in version 3.0.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems that UIKit updated their Less files such that the issue is no longer fixed. However, I can confirm that this workaround is still valid.